# does DateTime keep itself updated in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to create a folder based off of the current month/day using DateTime. After i initialize a new DateTime( 2011, 5, 16, 1, 1, 30); will this keep itself updated or reset every time the program is ran?

Comment: How would you expect it to get updated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A DateTime(2011, 5, 16, 1, 1, 30); is an object which gets initialized with the date you provide as a constructor. The date will always stay the same. If you want to get the current date then you need to use `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: It should be noted that the value returned from DateTime.Now does not update itself, it's just that DateTime.Now returns a new object each time.

Answer (score 2):

Try DateTime.Now - it will always get the current time.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use `DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 1):

When you give specific parameters in your `DateTime` instantiation, you will get the same date/time.

If you want to use the current time, and have that update each time you run the program, use `DateTime.Now`.

Answer (score 1):

A `DateTime` object is immutable and once created will never change.  `DateTime.Now` creates a new `DateTime` based on the current time, and will be correct at the time of creation, but the returned instance will not update.  You can always call `DateTime.Now` again to get the latest time, but don't keep a reference around and expect it to update.

```
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan elapsed = dt2 - dt;
        Console.WriteLine(elapsed.TotalMilliseconds); 
        // Printed 1000.4 when I last ran it, depends on CPU timings
```

As you can see `dt` and `dt2` are different because `dt` did not keep updated, it was only the time when that line of code was executed.

Answer (score 0):

If the code looks like that it will be the same every time.  If you want the the current day use `DateTime.Today` or `DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 0):

No, `DateTime` is not a Clock object of any kind, it's just an object that represents a moment in time. Use `DateTime.Now` if you always need to get the current moment in time.